# MS Access On_Current event not firing on very first run of the application

Tags: ms-access

I have an MS Access front end application in which the first form to be opened (a splash screen - the form is opened from the Autoexec Macro) has an on_Load event which sets the timer interval to 0, and an on current event which sets it to 100.  The timer event starts the application running (attaching to the backend SQL Server Database etc).

When a fresh copy of the application is copied to a new place - we do that when there is a new release - it gets copied to each users machine, the very first call of the application acts as through the timer never fires. In other words it appears the the on current event never fires.

I cannot find what is causing it, and my only explanation that I can think of is that in testing the start up just before release, I have set the form so its current record IS the one that is set when the form loads on start up.

Is this true?  Is there a situation anyone is aware of where the on_current event doesn't fire for that, or any other reason.

The reason I wait until the on_current event is that the form itself has a data-source which depending on the form filter sets the parameters for different databases to connect to (production v test for instance).  A work around may be to set the timer interval in the on load event - but it opens up to a possible race condition where the timer fires before on_current has set the correct database, and I would prefer to avoid that risk

Comment: I think the `On Current` event may only fire when the forms focus is set, have you tried programatically shifting the focus as this may trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

`On Current` fires when you move to a new record. To force it to fire, you might try to move to the last record, then back to the first.